# how to fix cors error in mongodb atlas data api

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, mongodb-atlas

this is the code

HERE this is giving me the cors error. i also added the allow access origin header but the issue is not solved

````
let headersList = {
 "Accept": "*/*",
 "User-Agent": "Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)",
 "api-key": "U5H4A6FcMbEuZ33LP0ACQHP0ydkXkGLLJnDfNzQzCXTpzxL8QdJ8tH7NocITeZvv",
 "Content-Type": "application/json" 
}

let bodyContent = JSON.stringify({
    "collection":"users",
    "database":"college",
    "dataSource":"Cluster0",
    "projection": {}
});

let reqOptions = {
  url: "  https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-tfdur/endpoint/data/beta/action/findOne",
  method: "POST",
  headers: headersList,
  body: bodyContent,
}

axios.request(reqOptions).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
})```
````

Comment: Watch out for the whitespaces at the beginning of `url` in `reqOptions`

Comment: Actually this is not the error.... The error is cors policy

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the MongoDB Data API does not support browser requests as CORS is not implemented.

There is a support page where you can vote to let them know the importance of this feature:

[MongoDB: Please Support CORS from the Data API](https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/945334-atlas-app-services/suggestions/44666878-please-support-cors-from-the-data-api)